AX-12A управление через Raspberry pi 4
У меня есть моторы AX-12A предназначены они сами для образовательного конструктора STEM. Однако разработчики выпустили source-code инструмент Dynamixel SDK. Я подключил контакты питания AX-12A к внешнему 11В источнику питания. Контакт Data подключил К TX пину UART (14 пин). Его имя в коде вывожу как /dev/ttyAMA0. Запускаю код-пример от Dynamixel SDK и нету никакой реакции от мотора. Id выставлен верный, baudrate 1мб/с, UART включен и код запускается без ошибок.
Код: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MJp0Bg_IC5AQWy5K8ycobIjEarcTdbhe?usp=sharing
import os

if os.name == 'nt':
    import msvcrt
    def getch():
        return msvcrt.getch().decode()
else:
    import sys, tty, termios
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    def getch():
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

from dynamixel_sdk import *                    # Uses Dynamixel SDK library

# Control table address
ADDR_MX_TORQUE_ENABLE      = 64               # Control table address is different in Dynamixel model
ADDR_MX_GOAL_POSITION      = 116
ADDR_MX_PRESENT_POSITION   = 132

# Protocol version
PROTOCOL_VERSION            = 1.0               # See which protocol version is used in the Dynamixel

# Default setting
DXL_ID                      = 1                 # Dynamixel ID : 1
BAUDRATE                    = 1000000             # Dynamixel default baudrate : 57600
DEVICENAME                  = '/dev/ttyAMA0'    # Check which port is being used on your controller
                                                # ex) Windows: "COM1"   Linux: "/dev/ttyUSB0" Mac: "/dev/tty.usbserial-*"

TORQUE_ENABLE               = 1                 # Value for enabling the torque
TORQUE_DISABLE              = 0                 # Value for disabling the torque
DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE  = 10           # Dynamixel will rotate between this value
DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE  = 4000            # and this value (note that the Dynamixel would not move when the position value is out of movable range. Check e-manual about the range of the Dynamixel you use.)
DXL_MOVING_STATUS_THRESHOLD = 20                # Dynamixel moving status threshold

index = 0
dxl_goal_position = [DXL_MINIMUM_POSITION_VALUE, DXL_MAXIMUM_POSITION_VALUE]         # Goal position


# Initialize PortHandler instance
# Set the port path
# Get methods and members of PortHandlerLinux or PortHandlerWindows
portHandler = PortHandler(DEVICENAME)

# Initialize PacketHandler instance
# Set the protocol version
# Get methods and members of Protocol1PacketHandler or Protocol2PacketHandler
packetHandler = PacketHandler(PROTOCOL_VERSION)

# Open port
if portHandler.openPort():
    print("Succeeded to open the port")
else:
    print("Failed to open the port")
    print("Press any key to terminate...")
    getch()
    quit()


# Set port baudrate
if portHandler.setBaudRate(BAUDRATE):
    print("Succeeded to change the baudrate")
else:
    print("Failed to change the baudrate")
    print("Press any key to terminate...")
    getch()
    quit()

# Enable Dynamixel Torque
dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write1ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_MX_TORQUE_ENABLE, TORQUE_ENABLE)
if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
    print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
elif dxl_error != 0:
    print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))
else:
    print("Dynamixel has been successfully connected")

while 1:
    print("Press any key to continue! (or press ESC to quit!)")
    if getch() == chr(0x1b):
        break

    # Write goal position
    dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write4ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_MX_GOAL_POSITION, dxl_goal_position[index])
    if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
        print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
    elif dxl_error != 0:
        print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))

    while 1:
        # Read present position
        dxl_present_position, dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.read4ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_MX_PRESENT_POSITION)
        if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
        elif dxl_error != 0:
            print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))

        print("[ID:%03d] GoalPos:%03d  PresPos:%03d" % (DXL_ID, dxl_goal_position[index], dxl_present_position))

        if not abs(dxl_goal_position[index] - dxl_present_position) > DXL_MOVING_STATUS_THRESHOLD:
            break

    # Change goal position
    if index == 0:
        index = 1
    else:
        index = 0


# Disable Dynamixel Torque
dxl_comm_result, dxl_error = packetHandler.write1ByteTxRx(portHandler, DXL_ID, ADDR_MX_TORQUE_ENABLE, TORQUE_DISABLE)
if dxl_comm_result != COMM_SUCCESS:
    print("%s" % packetHandler.getTxRxResult(dxl_comm_result))
elif dxl_error != 0:
    print("%s" % packetHandler.getRxPacketError(dxl_error))

# Close port
portHandler.closePort()

